# How to hide address bar in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Is there any method to hide the address bar without entering the "Presentation mode" or "Fullscreen mode" in Chrome version 24?

I have tried `about:flags` but no compact navigation can be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like this too.

Unfortunately I believe 'Compact Navigation' is only available in Windows builds.

Comment: and unfortunately not even there anymore, evidently ("Compact Navigation" is not found in chrome://flags/ )

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't.  No address bar, isn't compact navigation, its no navigation!

I would ask why?  As it sounds like your solving the wrong problem!

Comment: I want a compact navigation because I have obscured content of a website and the address bar is the only content that I cannot obscure.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by obscured content?  I know Google we're one of the first to make sure the address was visible on all windows (even popups), as this is a useful tool against scams and malware.

Comment: I'd like to hide it for video content from a certain site. it's taking up real-estate.